# MySQL concatenating all columns

Tags: mysql, database

Why can we not concatenate in MySQL using the * keyword?

```
SELECT concat(*) FROM table
```

or

```
SELECT group_concat(*) FROM table
```

Is there any other way we could access values in a column without explicitly using the columns name?

Comment: What would be the practical use for such functionality?

Comment: You can query `information_schema.columns` to get a list of columns and insert them into the query yourself.

Comment: Well, let's say I have 100 columns and would like to select them all concatenated to a string seperated by commas. Would be quite some work to enter 100 column names manually. But also why is there the * keyword in the first place then?

Comment: `group_concat()` is used to group values from multiple **rows** within the **same** column. So that obviously won't work. `concat` is a varargs function, so you obviously need to provide at least 2 arguments in order to concatenate something.

Comment: Why not just fetch the row into your application as an array, and implode the array into a comma-separated string?

Comment: A practical use would be to run several SELECTs on a single query, when the results have different formats or nr of columns. Columns can be CONCATenated into a single one, and then rows can be put together via UNION. May reduce the nr of calls to the mysql server.

Comment: Another practical use is that I find CONCAT()  to be far, far faster (sometimes 10X) than looping though the columns in the client program, as an example, using the ODBC in VBA and splitting the results to the Excel columns.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

To concatenate all columns in a table, you can't use the `*` keyword, but you need to explicitly list all columns:

```
SELECT CONCAT(col1, col2, col3, ....)
FROM yourtable
```

or you might want to use `CONCAT_WS` that will skip null values:

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(',', col1, col2, col3, ....)
FROM yourtable
```

If you don't want to specify all column names manually, you could use a dinamic query. This query will return all column names of your table:

```
SELECT `column_name` 
FROM   `information_schema`.`columns` 
WHERE  `table_schema`=DATABASE() 
       AND `table_name`='yourtable';
```

and using GROUP_CONCAT you can obtain a list of all column names:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('`', column_name, '`'))
```

quoted, in a comma separated format:

```
`col1`,`col2`,`col3`,`col4`,...
```

so now we have all the elements to create our query dinamically:

```
SELECT
  CONCAT(
    'SELECT CONCAT_WS(\'\',',
    GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('`', column_name, '`') ORDER BY column_name),
    ') AS all_columns FROM yourtable;')
FROM   `information_schema`.`columns` 
WHERE  `table_schema`=DATABASE() 
       AND `table_name`='yourtable'
INTO @sql;
```

this query will set the @sql string to something like:

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS('', col1, col2, col3, ....) AS all_columns FROM yourtable
```

and this code will execute it:

```
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/16df21/1).

Comment: You really healped me! Thank u so much!

Comment: Humm, maybe we can combine PREPARE with SHOW columns FROM your-table;?