# MySQL: possible to use CONCAT with *?

Tags: mysql, triggers, concatenation

I would like to get all field values in a SELECT in **one** comma separated text field.
When I know the fields beforehand I could just use :

```
SELECT CONCAT(Field1, Field2, Field3) FROM items
```

but now I'm wondering if it's possible to do something like :

```
SELECT CONCAT(*) FROM items
```

I know how to use INFORMATION_SCHEMA to get all fieldnames, but I can't use these in a SELECT (without using prepared statements, which I need to avoid since I need this inside a trigger).

Any ideas?

Comment: Certainly there is no other way, you will need to know the column names before using `CONCAT()`

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL concatenating all columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23348170/mysql-concatenating-all-columns)