# mysql SELECT WHERE only specific columns have values

Tags: mysql

Good day

I have a table with a dozen columns and i'm looking for a query that will return rows that only have specific columns filled up. So it shouldn't return rows where 'illegal' columns are filled up.

Something like:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE col1 is NOT NULL 
AND all_other_cols is NULL;
```

^ i know it can be done by listing every other column and indicating "not NULL", but is there another way of doing this?

Hopefully this makes sense

UPDATE:

Based on the answers below I'll just use "DESCRIBE my_table;" then build a query that will filter all unwanted columns with 'is NULL'

Comment: Checking all columns is the cleanest approach and might be the best in terms of optimization. If you want something simpler, have a look at `COALESCE`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no direct feature for that. But what you *can* do is this:

You concatenate all table columns to a single string and then test that string against the column that is *not* meant to be `NULL`. These two values can only be identical if all other columns are empty or hold `NULL`.

The answer to this question might help with how to even simplify that:

[MySQL concatenating all columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23348170/mysql-concatenating-all-columns)

Comment: thank you i thought of that as well, so there's something like CONCAT_WS but for column names?

Comment: Take a look at the question I referenced.

Comment: I think i'll just end up using DESCRIBE my_table; then build a query with 'unwanted col is NULL', seems to be the simplest, thanks for confirming that there's no direct feature for this

Answer (score 1):

I think your approach is the simplest one

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. This should have been a comment.

Answer (score 1):

You could use ISNULL condition : [check out here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/is-null-optimization.html)

Comment: The OP wrote that he knows about that, but that it is not what he is looking for...

Comment: True, but the link I gave is about optimizing isnull if he decides to use it. I should have written my answer in another way